# Can I link multiple Azure subscription to single Team Services accounts(VSTS)?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

So I have a single Visual studio account with 3 project in it and I have three different azure subscription for deploying these projects. But I can able to link one of the subscription to VSTS. But other two are I am not able to do linking.

I did some searching on this stuff got a link saying that it is not possible : [1](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/set-up-billing-for-your-account-vs#CannotLinkVSOAccount)

So can anybody help me on this situation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Microsoft's licensing policy, not about coding.

Comment: No its not, it's a technical issue for deployment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only link a single subscription to a VSTS account.

That is however for paying for services for VSTS. For deployment you can setup as many connections as you like on the Services tab in the administration.

[image]

You can add as many Service Endpoints as you like then use them in Tasks in both Build and Release.

Comment: Does this also mean that a single AD needs to be used to authenticate across subscriptions being deployed to? I.e. Each subscriptions AD needs to be common. Getting errors like this: Failed to obtain the Json Web Token(JWT) for service principal id 'b90bd010-0ca6-4c47-a610-7db1c506aad3'. Exception Message: AADSTS70001: Application with identifier 'b90bd010-0ca6-4c47-a610-7db1c506aad3' was not found in the directory xxx-5290-4fd1-a938-xxx.

Comment: No, you can have multiple AAD in a subscription, and multiple Accounts. Each account can link to one AAD but they dojt have to be the same.

Comment: Did you delete the AAD that was in there?

Comment: Hmm, VSTS is linked to an Azure subscription that is using its default directory. The Service Endpoint I am creating is so I can deploy to a different Azure subscription. No I have not deleted any AAD's.

Comment: I think I have found the issue, our EA team has the default directory as their own and I do not have permission within it. I will have this changed to give me access and I suspect the issue will be resolved.